# Running synchronous methods in a web service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, asynchronous

I am out of town unfortunately and cannot test something I need to convey to my associates, so I was hoping for some help.

When I create a service reference to a web service and check the asynchronous check box, I notice that even though my web service has **all asynchronous** methods in it, the proxy or metadata on the client also creates **synchronous** versions of the same method.

In other words, I have a method on my web service called *GetCategoriesAsync*. Even though there is no method written for *GetCategories*, the Reference.cs file on the client (inside the service reference) automatically generates it. I am also able to execute this method in the WCF Service Test Client.

My question is, am I able to have my choice of calling the synchronous or asynchronous method from my client and it will show up via intellisense? Obviously, this would assume calling the appropriate method with or without the *async, Task* and *await* keywords or not.

Answer (score 2):

Server and client are separated by the network. Neither of the care what the other does to generate the bytes that the web-services protocol specifies. Neither of them can detect whether the other is synchronous or asynchronous.

Pick what you like.

You can have sync server-side implementations and async client-side stub methods. Just have the generator emit the async versions and you can call any service in an async way. "they will still show up via intellisense...?" - yes, everything you generate will show up, of course. Generate them if you need them.

TL;DR: If you want to use async methods, generate them and use them. You do not need to modify the server. If you do not own the server (maybe it is a 3rd party non-.NET server), you can still call it in an async way.

Comment: In other words, all I/O is inherently asynchronous. The synchronous methods in your client proxy are just going to block on the asynchronous operations. BTW, this is true even if all your web service methods are synchronous.

Comment: Stephen, bottom line is I can use either the synchronous or asynchronous method calls. Correct? I understand perfectly about the blocking if using synchronous call. What I'm curious about is, even though I don't have physical code for the synchronous methods, they will still show up via intellisense which were generated in the proxy. Correct?

Comment: What do you mean, physical code? If you mean server-side code - it does not matter. You can have sync server-side implementations and async client-side stub methods. Just have the generator emit the async versions and you can call any service in an async way. "they will still show up via intellisense...?" - yes, everything you generate will show up, of course. Generate them if you need them. If this does not answer your question, please clarify.

Comment: But, if a webservice is defined as synchronous at server side, it would return a response on all cost. It depends on client whether you want to display it or not. I am not tech savvy in wcf client but concept would be same. On contrary if you wont accept that response at client side in your code, you must be getting some error.

Comment: @user3090039 I don't know what you're saying exactly. The server always returns a response. It does not matter to the client how it generates it. From the perspective of the client this process always looks the same. What is so hard to understand about this? I'm running out of ways to explain this.